# Angular2: Handle selections on an list with RXJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-components

I have a simple list of things coming from an `$http` request.

I directly render the stream using `ngFor` plus `AsyncPipe`

```
<li *ngFor="let item of campaign$ | async">
```

Every element in the list has a checkbox to select it

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.selected (click)="selectElement(item)" />

selectElement(item) {
    item.selected = !item.selected
}
```

Then i have a "delete" button that should delete all the selected items

1. How am i suppose to handle the selection in a way that the stream is updated with the new value each time? Clearly just setting `item.selected` doesn't modify the stream
2. How can i extract from `campaigns$` a subset of items (the `selected` ones) using streams so without looping campaign$.value?. Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

Let's assume i create a new stream of `selection$` so i can merge this stream with `campaigns$`.
How i'm i supposed to add/remove the selections from the stream without getting and resetting `selection$.value`?